# Upload file from angular 6 to web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2, angular6

Upload image from angular 6 to web api 2, i was success from postman but not from my angular app.

i use many of tutorials like:1)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c61wr1ZsHzY,
2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y&t=534s

but Anytime I fall on

```
if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
    }
```

what am I missing? The only change is that in my Angular I use the **Interceptor**
and the headers goes like:

```
 req = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Accept'       : 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${decodedString}`,
  },
});
```

all the rest code are exacly like the first tutorial

if you guys need more details, please let me know

thanks

Comment: You're adding a header to say it's JSON, not form data

Comment: i was trying to form data in the other , but everything was the same, its not help

Comment: That's good, but check the network tab of your browser's debugger tools. It looks like your interceptor is going to set the "Content-Type" to `application/json`, so when it gets to your backend `request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data")` will never be true

Comment: when i send form data in the header its still not working )-:

Comment: If you inspect in the developer tools network tab, what value is it sending for the `Content-Type` header? And is the body being properly encoded as form data as well?

Comment: right! thanx a lot!  I understood what it was. The problem now is that I have to send a media-type all the time instead of a Content-type in the Interceptor, for example:                     req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'media-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; application/json; charset=utf-8;',
         'Accept'       : 'multipart/form-data; application/json;',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${decodedString}`,
      },
    });     How am I going to change it as needed? Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that setting the "media-type" header is what fixed the issue (I can't find that header documented anywhere). By not setting the "content-type" header manually, it leaves Angular to do it for you, which sets it correctly. If I were you, I would remove that line from your interceptor, so that the interceptor only sets your `Authorization` header, and that should fix your issue I think

Comment: user184994 your totally right! the authorization is enough at the interceptor. and its work amazing

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a sample application if you want to look at it.

https://github.com/sfjadi2010/HCTask

Let me know if you have any question.

Thanks 
Salman